# How to change value in a loop?

Tags: python

Tell me how to make the value change in the loop when the command is needed:

```
for k, v in sorted(news_dict.items())[-2:-1]
```

e.g. always when I give the command "next" should add (-1). From [-2:-1] to [-3:-2] then [-4:-3] etc.

Comment: you want to iterate on different slices, one after another ?

Comment: Show example data, desired output, and explain a little more what you want.

Comment: I have a button in the telegram bot, when pressed, this process should occur - [-2:-1], pressed the button - [-3:-2], pressed the button - [-4:-3], pressed the button - [-5:-4] etc.

Comment: use variables and decrement them in click function

Comment: @Mr.CXer Please [edit] your question to clarify.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say add another loop that will change these values

```
values = sorted(news_dict.items())
for i in range(1, 10):
    for k, v in values[-i - 1:-i]:
        print(k, v)
```

Comment: Thank you, it's really easier, but in your case, when you press the button, let's say, the process will go immediately from 1 to 10. Is it possible to do it in stages? like this: pressed the button - [-3:-2], pressed the button - [-4:-3], pressed the button - [-5:-4]

Comment: @Mr.CXer sorry but it seems you question mentionned only half of the issue, you now talk about a bot and button, I won't answer to that, I have no knowledge on that topic